# Get statistic about cancer after radiotherapy

Tags: binary-data, paired-data

I have 100 patients all with specific benign tumor. They have radiotherapy and removed tumor. Some of them have secondary cancer after more than 15 years.

**Our question is, what is a probablity, they will get secondary radiotherapy cancer?** From biological aspect please forget tumor relaps, genetics predisposition and multifacotrial predispositions.

Data looks like simply:

```
patient    radiation-cancer (more than 15 years)  date of birth   follow_up
a          0                                      1.1.2000        1.1.2020
b          1                                      27.1.1998       1.1.2022
c          1                                      15.2.1997       3.1.2022
d          0                                      14.3.1995       2.3.2022
e          0                                      16.3.2002       12.8.2004
```

where `0` means no secondary cancer and patient is healthy and `1` they have some secondary findings.

I was thinking about A Kaplan-Meier test, but this is probably not right one.

Thank you for any help.

Best Paul.

EDIT: I just added based on @EdM additional information (date of birth and follow up).

Comment: Do you have any information about when the secondary tumors developed, or just that they had one at 15 years after radiotherapy? Do you have any information about individuals who had radiotherapy but were lost to follow-up before 15 years? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Dear @EdM, thank you for comment, I just have date of birth and follow up afther this seconary cancer as found.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do here is to report the percentage of individuals in your sample who developed the secondary findings at 15+ years.* All you know is that the secondary finding developed, not when.

Survival analysis, as with Kaplan-Meier curves, requires information about when the event occurred. With the data you show, all that you know is age and status at follow up.

If you *know for a fact* that all individuals had the radiotherapy *very soon after birth*, you perhaps could use the date of birth as a `time = 0` reference. Then you could get some information from the interval-censored times to events for those who had secondary findings: for them you know that the time to event is greater than 0 and less than the age at follow up. Those without events at follow up would have corresponding right censored times. The R `survfit()` function can produce survival curves for such combinations of interval- and right-censored data.

Even that might not be very satisfying, as it's quite possible that those who had such early radiotherapy and were lost to follow up had different outcomes. For example, some of those might have had an aggressive, fatal secondary cancer.

---

*Your patient `e` can't properly be evaluated as of 15+ years; less than 3 years since birth. Your analysis needs to address that problem, if you're using a 15-year cutoff. If you can reliably allow date of birth to serve as `time = 0` as I suggest later in the answer, those individuals could be included with their ages at follow up as right-censored survival times.

Comment: Dear @EdM, basically at the time of follow-up was time of secondary findigs (sorry for wrong explanation).

Comment: Dear @EdM, basically at the time of follow-up was time of secondary findigs (sorry for wrong explanation). And Also I can have information abou time of diagnosis cancer (starting radiotherapy - colleague gaves me this). So for Survival Analysis - I can use this as: survival <- with(my_patiens, Surv(time, status)), as a time is from first time of diagnosis cancer to follow-up and status is 1 or 0 to have secondary cancer? What do you think?

Comment: @Paul if you have reliable dates for the initial diagnosis and for the detection of secondary cancer you can use survival analysis as you propose. The question then becomes whether you have a representative sample of those who had the initial diagnosis. The danger is that you are more likely to have follow up on patients who developed the secondary cancer, while those who didn't develop the secondary cancer might have been lost to further study. That would tend to over-estimate the risk of secondary cancer development.